# Multiline TextView not processing newline character

Tags: android, textview, newline

For some reason, my multi line TextView is not processing \n as a new line character. Am I doing something wrong? I have tried using `.setText()` to set a String which has multiple instances of "\n", but the string just appears as one line with the \n visible as text.

This is my TextView.

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/noteText"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:maxHeight="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ActivityTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:editable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
/>
```

Thanks

Edit: Small snippet:

```
noteText.setText(result);
//result == "Testing\nTest"
```

Comment: could you show a snippet of how you are calling setText, are you using double quotes/single quotes?

Comment: Just posted one. Result is set earlier to "Testing\nTest"

Comment: InputType to Multiline itself provides you entering button on keyboard.

Comment: Is there a different way to do it then?>

Comment: Make sure you set android:maxLines, and try running it on a emulator or an actual device and make sure it still behaves that way

Comment: How about noteText.setText("Testing\nTest");

Comment: You are talking about TextView but giving an EditText as example. By the way I tried your code without problem, are you sure there is no other constraint on this widget ?